# How to group the subtotal in the report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-7

using crystal report 7

Single report (no sub report added, group by id)

```
ID Value total

001 100 2000
001 200 3000
-------------
total 300 5000 (a)

002 300 1000
002 200 2000
-------------
total 500 3000 (b)

003 300 1000
003 200 2000
-------------
total 500 3000 (c)

......
```

I have n number of subtotal like a, b, c ....., each subtotal i want to make subtotal2/ subtotal1 like b/a, c/a .....

Expected Ouput

```
ID Value total subtotal

001 100 2000
002 200 3000
-------------------
total 300 5000 0

002 300 1000
002 200 2000
-------------------
total 500 3000 0.6

003 300 1000
003 200 1000
-------------------
total 500 2000 0.4

......
```

How to do it in crystal report.

Can any one give me a idea or formula help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me, as I have not worked with a version of Crystal that old, but hopefully at least one of these solutions will be suitable:

- Create a subreport in the report header which will pull the total of group a. Create a formula along the lines: `shared numbervar total_a := sum({table.total});`
- In the main report group footer add a formula along the lines: `shared numbervar total_a; sum({table.total}) / total_a;`

OR similar to the above solution:

- Create a formula in the report header: `global numbervar total_a := 0;`
- Create a formula in the group footer: `global numbervar total_a; if total_a = 0 then total_a := sum({table.total}); sum({table.total}) / total_a;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you ellaporate you answer, still i am confused.  I want to solve this...

Comment: Start by trying the second solution. Place the first formula field: `global numbervar total_a := 0;` in the report header, then in your ascii diagram place the second formula where the 0 is (should be the group footer): `global numbervar total_a; if total_a = 0 then total_a := sum({table.total}); sum({table.total}) / total_a;`. What happens?